# git recommit changes made to subbranch-a to subbranch-b

Tags: git, merge, branch, rebase

I currently have a problem in which my feature branch is not up to date with master,
resolving the conflict seem to take too much time in comparison how small the actual change is.

My idea what to make a new branch, featurev2 from master, and recommit the changes I made onto feature to featurev2.

But how do I do that?

Merge would conflict with files I haven't changed + those I have changed, which will get me back to my initial problem.

So how do I properly resolve this?

Is there a way to add only commit I made to feature on to featurev2, and keep the latest master changes?

Comment: I am not sur I understand what you intend to achieve. You want master to be equal to your current feature branch?

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully understand, but I think you're describing the same thing that [`git rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) gives you. With your feature branch checked out, `git rebase master` will remove all the commits since your feature branch diverged from master, bring your feature branch up to date with the current master, and then add each of your commits back on, one-by-one, so you end up with a nice clean history with no merges, and just your commits on top of the current tip of master.

Comment: Git merge gives no error

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for [`git rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) or [`git cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick)

```
git checkout -b featurev2 feature
git rebase master
```

or

```
git checkout -b featurev2 master
git cherry-pick master..feature
```